# How to import ExtJs framework to Eclipse

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have installed VJET plugin to Eclipse and I'd like to import ExtJs framework to be able to use code assistant to develop RIAs.

I searched google but haven't found type libs!

Need help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version ?
3.x ? 4.x ?
must it to use vjet plugin???

i would rather use spket plugin to develop extjs

old version:
http://www.spket.com/demos/js.html

for Ext 4 (tested):
http://www.spket.com/extjs.html

Comment: I am using 4.x version! Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Thanks, Warun Nasi! I got it to work. The autocomplete is working cool!

Answer (score 1):

use following link. It will help to  solve 3.XX and 4.XX issues

http://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/eclipse-extjs-jquery/

Comment: The article is not up to date: The URL `http://www.spket.com/update` doesn't work anymore. Use `http://www.agpad.com/update/`. For ExtJs 4.2 you have to use the `Folder Method`